# How to run function after specific buffer has been saved

Tags: hooks

If i want to run function when buffer "k" is saved, is there a better way to do this, then just using add hook and checking buffers name in function?

Comment: Define *"better*"? What kind of difference are you looking for? What are your criteria/expectations? The question is vague so far, and so risks being closed as too broad.

Comment: Can you add more information to your post, such as what you exactly want to accomplish (at least a rough description of what your function is supposed to do, whether the buffer is expected to be pointed to a particular file)?

Comment: Down-voted due to the lack of any response to multiple requests for clarification, in order to prevent the question being automatically bumped in future.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to check the buffer name. Just add the hook buffer-locally.
See the doc of `add-hook`:

> The optional fourth argument, LOCAL, if non-nil, says to modify
>   the hooks buffer-local value rather than its global value.
>   This makes the hook buffer-local, and it makes t a member of the
>   buffer-local value.  That acts as a flag to run the hook
>   functions of the global value as well as in the local value.

The fourth argument with value `t` says that the hook is buffer-local:

```
(add-hook 'after-save-hook #'your-function nil t)
```

Comment: Wouldn't that require 1) the hook be added locally within that specific buffer and 2) the buffer to currently exist?  How would you define that in `init.el`?  I suppose you could use file variables, but then that's clutter in the source file.  Or do something like `(let* ((buff (get-buffer "name")))
  (if buff
      (with-current-buffer buff
 (add-hook 'after-save-hook #'your-function nil t))
    (message "That buffer DNE")))`

Comment: @LoremIpsum I understand the question such that he has already the buffer. Maybe the buffer has a special major mode and he can add the hook function there.